# C++ Qt: Can't compile GoldenDict

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary, compilation, locale

I have downloaded the source of GoldenDict from the website and using Git repository, but I can't compile it. There are some locale files missing that I don't understand their relation to the program. The website says that there are no third-party libraries needed.

I'm trying to compile it with Visual Studio 2010.

What can I do to get those locale files? please check the error message:

```
11:13:10: Running build steps for project goldendict...
11:13:10: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:13:10: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Error: dependent 'locale\ru_RU.qm' does not exist.
jom 1.0.8 - empower your cores

jom: D:\GoldenDictSrc\goldendict-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
11:13:10: The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project goldendict (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call lrelease in project directory first

Answer (score 0):

I’ve also faced this problem and resolved it.

You can disable **Shadow build** feature when opening GoldenDict project file at the first time or you can disable this feature later by click on **Projects** icon in the left panel of Qt Creator, uncheck **Shadow build** option.

Best regard,

[image: GoldenDict Project build settings]